# AWS Cloudformation Fn::GetAZs not working after timezone change

Tags: amazon-web-services, timezone, aws-cloudformation, availability-zone

I am using AWS Cloudformation to create an application that deploys some instances inside a cluster with an Autoscaling group. I'm deploying it at `us-east-1`

The thing is that yesterday we changed to Summertime, and my script stopped working, giving me a very weird error, because I had run the same script on Friday and it was working perfectly.

After some debugging, I found the culprit and it seems to be the intrinsic function `Fn::GetAZs`.

I was specifying my availability zones and subnets for the Autoscaling group and the error was:

**The availability zones of the specified subnets and the Auto Scaling group do not match**

After that I changed my script. Instead of having the following format:

```
AvailabilityZones:
     - Fn::Select:
       - '0'
       - Fn::GetAZs:
           Ref: AWS::Region
     - Fn::Select:
       - '1'
       - Fn::GetAZs:
           Ref: AWS::Region
     - Fn::Select:
       - '2'
       - Fn::GetAZs:
           Ref: AWS::Region
```

I used this format

```
AvailabilityZones:
    - us-east-1a
    - us-east-1b
    - us-east-1c
```

And it worked, but of course I can't have hardcoded values like that. This  lead me to think that after the timezone changed it started to fail. 
My current location is Belo Horizonte - Brazil

Is anyone facing the same issue ? Does it make sense ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you deploying to Virginia or São Paulo? I don't think your physical location makes any difference, since none of the processing is performed on the client side.

Comment: Be aware that for VPC, the Fn::GetAZs function returns **only** AZs that have a default subnet (unless none of the AZs has a default subnet, in which case **all** AZs are returned).

Comment: I'm deploying it at us-east-1

Comment: On the surface, it seems that the time change is coincidental and not related to the problem.  Sure - it's possible, but not likely.   Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44004118/634824) already?  Is that the same as what you are dealing with?

Comment: @jarmod thanks, I was deploying extra subnet as changeset to pick a new AZ dynamically and ran into the error. Deleting previous elements and re-creation too ran into same error `Template error: Fn::Select cannot select nonexistent value at index 1` 
``` 
     Fn::Select:
        - '1'
        - Fn::GetAZs:
            Ref: AWS::Region
```

Answer (score 0):

`Fn::GetAZs` returns availability zones in which you have default subnets in your default VPC. Maybe you deleted such subnects.

You have two options:

- recreate default VPC with default subnets;
- remove default VPC entirely.

Sidenote: `Fn::GetAZs` works in current region if not specified, so you don't need to use

```
Fn::GetAZs:
    Ref: AWS::Region
```

You can simplify it into:

```
Fn::GetAZs: ""
```